# How to create a glass transparent hexagon with CSS

Tags: css

[image]I would like to create frosted glass hexagon with css. I managed to create an hexagon with svg but i failed to apply a transparent glass on it. Here is what i have tried.

```css
svg{
    
    width:500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}



.node {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.hex-title {
    width:50px;
    height: 10px;
    font-size:8px;
}

.list {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 6px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <polygon fill="transparent"
                 fill-opacity=".7"
                 stroke="#000"
                 stroke-width="2"
                 points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"/>

     <foreignobject class="node" x="25" y="25">
        <div class="hex-title">Hexagone 1</div>                
     </foreignobject>
    <foreignobject class="node" x="25" y="45">
      <ul class="list">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>                
    </foreignobject>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit**: Answered before the picture was added. Check comments below for the glossy reflection effect.

---

I think you already achieved what you wanted (I think so because I saw your opacity value is set and is less than one).

If you want opacity to work it needs to have a visible color, not transparent as defined in your hexagon.

If you want to render things behind the hexagon, these things needs to be declared outside of it.

For example in the snippet below I use a white color.

```css
svg{
    
    width:500px;
    height: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.node {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.hex-title {
    width:50px;
    height: 10px;
    font-size:8px;
}

.list {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 6px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <polygon
        fill="white"
        fill-opacity=".7"
        stroke="#000"
        stroke-width="2"
        points="50 1 95 25 95 75 50 99 5 75 5 25"
    />
        <foreignobject class="node" x="25" y="25">
            <div class="hex-title">Hexagone 1</div>                
        </foreignobject>
    <foreignobject class="node" x="25" y="45">
        <ul class="list">
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>                
    </foreignobject>
</svg>
<div>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In tristique urna turpis. Phasellus eget justo eget nisl molestie euismod id in nunc. Nulla hendrerit luctus vulputate. Fusce vel mauris ultricies purus varius vestibulum. Morbi id semper orci. Donec ac euismod lectus. Etiam laoreet erat nibh, blandit rhoncus neque dictum quis. Quisque lobortis mi et gravida lobortis. Nam facilisis tortor neque, vel dictum quam sodales sit amet. Donec vitae mauris quis erat viverra lacinia.

Mauris venenatis leo id scelerisque posuere. Integer eget dictum urna. Maecenas interdum dolor felis, et congue orci convallis in. Vivamus quis gravida nulla. Donec ac ligula odio. Suspendisse ut ex suscipit, lobortis tortor nec, tempor libero. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla et fringilla eros, nec malesuada sapien. Aliquam fringilla, neque eu tristique ullamcorper, tellus nisl accumsan nulla, sed dignissim nulla velit id leo.

Curabitur eu facilisis augue. Pellentesque et felis pretium, consequat eros vel, feugiat justo. Donec a ultricies tellus, quis congue tortor. Aenean vitae sagittis elit. Vivamus a ligula libero. Pellentesque egestas, tortor eu efficitur ultrices, quam diam porttitor sem, quis venenatis libero eros id neque. Morbi tellus lorem, interdum lobortis lacinia a, facilisis in neque.
</div>
```

Comment: I want something that looks like the picture above.

Comment: @Xris You're going to need to combine `::after` and `::before` with gradients or some fairly intensive stuff to even come *half-way* to mimicking the image you've shared in your question. It's not a question of it can be done, the real question is: will the amount of effort made be worth the time invested?

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same as image, i just need something that is kind glass transparent.

Comment: what do you mean by glass transparent?

Comment: @Xris You added the picture 3 hours after my answer. How could have I know that you wanted some glossy reflection? I have not enough time to code it but what you are looking for are https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_grad_linear.asp. and for shiny spots a div with some https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient or even pictures (pictures are fine and simpler).